# How to find binary representation for n'th Fibonacci number

Tags: binary, fibonacci

Its my first post here, so if I commit some mistake please let me know.

I have been given a assignment, and a part of it requires the binary representation of n'th Fibonacci number.
Constraints-

1. ) C++ has to be used as prog. language.
2. ) n'th fib. number has to be calculated in lg(n) time.

I have a function but it works on integers. But the maximum value for which I have to do calculations is about 10^6. So, I am badly stuck here.
Whatever I know, I can't apply in this scenario, because I can generate n'th fib. using strings but that will have linear time complexity. 
following is the function,

```
void multiply(long int F[2][2], long int M[2][2]);
void power(long int F[2][2], long int n);

// Function to Calculate n'th fibonacci in log(n) time
long int fib(long int n)
{
    long int F[2][2] = {{1,1},{1,0}};
    if(n == 0)
        return 0;
    power(F, n-1);
    return F[0][0];
}

void power(long int F[2][2], long int n)
{
    if( n == 0 || n == 1)
        return;
    long int M[2][2] = {{1,1},{1,0}};

    power(F, n/2);
    multiply(F, F);

    if( n%2 != 0 )
        multiply(F, M);
}

void multiply(long int F[2][2], long int M[2][2])
{
    long int x =  (F[0][0]*M[0][0])%mod + (F[0][1]*M[1][0])%mod;
    long int y =  (F[0][0]*M[0][1])%mod + (F[0][1]*M[1][1])%mod;
    long int z =  (F[1][0]*M[0][0])%mod + (F[1][1]*M[1][0])%mod;
    long int w =  (F[1][0]*M[0][1])%mod + (F[1][1]*M[1][1])%mod;  
    F[0][0] = x;
    F[0][1] = y;
    F[1][0] = z;
    F[1][1] = w;
}

int main(){
    int n; cin >> n; cout << fib(n)<<endl; getchar();
}
```

As it can be seen, only predefined data types can be used in this function.

Comment: "I have found a function while searching over the net " - isn't the idea of an assignment that you do it yourself?

Comment: sorry to say, but my solution on which I really worked hard, was rejected(that was in Java).I am using internet for the first time for assignment because I have absolutely no idea how to proceed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better method would be to use Matrix Exponentiation, which would calculate n'th fib. in lg(n) time. ( usefull for various online coding contests) See Method 4 of [This](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/) post.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I'll only give you little hints.

The two problems are unrelated, so you need two methods: toBinary and fib. `toBinary (fib (n));` would be your solution.

For solving the toBinary part, division and modulo are useful and can be called recursively.

If you calculate fib (n) as fib (n-1) + fib (n-2), there is a trap to step into, that when you calculate fib (n-1) as fib (n-2) + fib (n-3), you end up calculating fib (n-2) twice, fib (n-3) three times and so on.

Instead, you should start from (0 + 1) and step upwards, passing already calculated forward.

---

After a short test, I see how fast the Fibonacci numbers are growing. Do you have access to Ints of arbitrary size, or are you expected to use preallocated arrays?

Then you would need an add method, which takes the lower and the higher number as array of Integers or Booleans, and creates the sum in the lower array, which then becomes the upper array.

---

## update:

Since you solved the problem, I feel free to post my solution for reference, written in Scala:

```
import annotation._
/**
  add two arrays recursively. carry the position pos and the overrun 
   overrun=0   = 1      0      1      0      1
   Sum    low        | next        |  Sum
          0 1        | overrun     |  %2
  high 0| 0 1   1 2  | 0 0    0 1  | 0 1    1 0 
       1| 1 2   2 3  | 0 1    1 1  | 1 0    0 1
*/
@tailrec 
def add (low: Array[Int], high: Array[Int], pos: Int = 0, overrun: Int = 0): Array[Int] = {
  if (pos == higher.size) {
    if (overrun == 0) low else sys.error ("overrun!")
  } else {
    val sum = low (pos) + high (pos) + overrun
    low (pos) = (sum % 2)
    add (low, high, pos + 1, if (sum > 1) 1 else 0)
  }
}

/** call cnt (example: 5) steps of 
   fib (5, 0, 1), 
   fib (4, 1, 1), 
   fib (3, 1, 2), 
   fib (2, 2, 3), 
   fib (1, 3, 5), 
   fib (0, 5, 8) */
@tailrec 
def fib (cnt: Int, low: Array[Int], high: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
  if (cnt == 0) low else fib (cnt - 1, high, add (low, high)) }

/** generate 2 Arrays, size dependent on n of about 0.7*n + 1, big enough to
    hold values and result. Result has to be printed in reverse order, from the highest bit
*/
def fibonacci (n: Int) = {
  val lower =  Array.fill (n * 7 / 10 + 1)(0) // [...000]
  val higher = Array.fill (n * 7 / 10 + 1)(0) // [...000]
  higher (0) = 1 // [...001]
  val res = fib (n, lower, higher)
  res.reverse.foreach (print)
  println ()
  res
}

fibonacci (n)
```

For fibonacci (10000) I get a result of nearly 7000 binary digits, and the relation 10/7 is constant, so the millionth Fibonacci digit will have about 1.4 M digits.

Comment: thanks for the hint.
I never thought this way.
I worked on it and finally got it. had some problems in converting large decimal strings into binary but at last I did it.
I had to calculate upto 10^6'th fib. number.

Comment: @Bond: You're welcome. I worked with an Array of Booleans, while a BitSet might have been the better choice, but for didactical reasons, probably not. I fear my solution is not lg(n): it takes 4s for fib(10k), 11s for 20k, 40s for 40k, 240s for 100k.